# Heroku logs : Service temporarily unavailable. Please try again later

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, logging

**FIRST :**
When I run in my terminal : heroku logs or heroku logs `--tail`, I get

> "Service temporarily unavailable. Please try again later"

What does it mean please ?

**SECOND :**
I add in my `index.js`

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
```

In my `mongoose.js`

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/bonapp-api', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
})
```

And I add in my heroku app :

```
MONGODB_URI = mongodb+srv://root:****@bonapp.nzbvf.mongodb.net/*****?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

But when I send request in my heroku app I get :

> POST https://example.herokuapp.com/users [HTTP/1.1 503 Service
> Unavailable 30296ms]

Please help..

Comment: can you share some more logs.
One possible reason is that you are not having a start script in your package.json file

Comment: in log :UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/.

Comment: but my ip is in the whiteList

Comment: What ip have you whitelisted.????

Comment: For heroku you need to Whitelist 0.0.0.0/0, and restart your dyno.it will work

Comment: I am getting this error when trying to reset any dyno. Heroku status okay

Comment: @MoteZart I have currently the problem with a nodejs app, not working. Browser is loading and no content.Maybe their Node Server is not available. The PHP app works. `heroku run bash` outputs `Error: Service temporarily unavailable`